# R Studio Viewer issue

Tags: csv, rstudio, numeric

I am running the folliwing code:

```
trial = read.csv("trial.csv",
               header = TRUE,             
               sep = ",",                 
               na.string = "NA",           
               skip = 0,                  
               strip.white = TRUE,        
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

which I've successfully run for 3 previous datasets. No problem, I eventually merged them and did my stuff.

However, on this one I can't understand what's going on: the dataset doesn't open. I've tried to see which column was giving me the problem and it is the sixth

```
x<-trial[6]
```

which is the only numeric one. So i thought it was a conversion problem (the string one, even if I put the code in the import one.
But it is not this problem, since when I run

```
str(trial)
```

it gives me `num`, as it should.

It's been a week I've been trying to solve this apparently simple problem but I can't pull though.

EDIT2 The IMF dataset I0m using can be freely downloaded at [this link](http://data.imf.org/?sk=5DABAFF2-C5AD-4D27-A175-1253419C02D1&sId=1390030341854&ss=1390030341854). You need to register (free) to do the bulk download at the top right. I'm not sure if this is the right way to link a dataset, pls let me know.
When you download the dataset, just choose one country (e.g. Italy) and leave the option "all indicators".

EDIT. There is no shown error message.

Comment: Any error/warning messages you could share? "doesn't open" isn't very specific.

Comment: One of the common problems I encounter of such failure is when a character column of some kind has a comma in its values. The CSV gets messed up. More details an help resolve.

Comment: the data & error msg wld be handy

Comment: Can you provide a link to your `csv` file ?

Comment: Please provide the code that led to the eventual data set not being open (ie. please provide a reproducible example for us)

Comment: I could import the dataset, it took quite long but in my case it is working...   summary(trial[6]) gives: Min.   :-8.081e+24, 1st Qu.: 0.000e+00, Median : 1.143e+07, Mean   : 7.872e+21, 3rd Qu.: 2.941e+09, Max.   : 2.012e+28, NA's   :321320

Comment: Thank you very much @mountrix for trying. All statistics work (fortunately). The problem is just a visualization one (View dataset)..does it work for you?

Comment: @mountrix do you have the same View problem or is it something else I did it wrong?

Comment: Can you post here the command you use for visualization? I will try it. It is a 2 GB dataset so I guess it is probably related to the memory you have.

Comment: It's just the normal View(data), which you can use just by clicking on the dataset in the global envirnoment. Memory would be a nice explanation..